# Kubernetes Load Balancing with Redis Cluster and microservices

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, cluster, redis

I have the following scenario:

N kubernetes Nodes
A redis cluster with N instances, each node has a single instance
There are requests coming into the nodes in a round-robin format
After the requests, my data is processed by microservices that are communicating through Redis lists that are named the following way: <SERVICE_PREFIX>:{CLUSTER_HASH_SLOT}
On the the Nodes I have a network packet rate limit that I would like to solve with this approach, because we are constantly on the edge of hitting it. (Mostly because of the node-to-node communications)

Assumption: After the request comes in and is pushed to the correct Redis instance, it will not leave the node, since we will always use the same hash slot, and therefore the same Redis instance.

If this is the case then this will solve my problem, because if I get closer to the limit I can just boot up additional nodes, with the same configuration.

**Is my assumption correct? Could this work?**
Anything that I might have missed?